# Windows - How to grep (or findstr) html files and showing the first matching expression

Tags: html, grep, findstr

using grep or findstr I want to get the correct IMDB number, when searching by a specific movie via it's real name.

For example the movie "Das Boot" is listed at IMDB with movie number tt0082096.

Actually I'm trying to grep (or findstr) through html files that are generated by a search machine.

The generated html file contains several parts like this:

```
<div id="statbox"> 
  <span class="uschr2">1. </span> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/" class="dublaulink">Das Boot (1981) - IMDb</a> <br>
  <div id="descbox"> 
  www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/ - Im Cache - Ähnliche Seiten <BR>
  </div>
```

The string I'm looking for is the one containing the URL of the movie. In this case it's:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/
```

The string format is like:

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt???????/
```

Where '?' stands for a digit 0...9

My question is:
How can grep or findstr return only the first occurrence of the matching string itself and not the complete line containing a match?

Thank you a lot for your assistance!
Best regards

Comment: you're doing that on a command line? i think you should try a HTML parser, with which you could select the first occurrence of the div#descbox...

Answer (score 3):

Windows `findstr` returns complete lines. You can avoid this with GNU [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed -rn "\#http://www.imdb.com/title/tt#s#.*href=\"(.*)\"\s.*#\1#p" file
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082096/
```

In addition you can use `grep -o`:

```
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

Comment: `grep -o` won't return complete line

Comment: @JS웃 yes, you are completely right, I will restrict this for `findstr`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` you can do something like:

```
grep -oP '(?<=href=\")[^"]+(?=\")' html.file
```

This is not the ideal way of parsing an html file. However, if it is a one off thing then you can probably get away with it. `?<=href=\"` is a look behind search. If the above it returning a lot of stuff then you can probably add which is unique to the url lines.